# Mapping values of grouped query?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, mapping

I'm new to C# and LINQ, so I'm unsure what the best practice for this would be:

I have an `IEnumerable<Something>`, where `Something` has properties A, B and C. I want to group my list of Somethings by the property A: However, I want the list of values for each group to be mapped to a different object, `TargetSomething`. I have a helper class, `MyHelper`, which has a static function converting any `Something` into a `TargetSomething`.

Therefore, I have source value / structure as follows:

```
IEnumerable<Something>
```

And target value / structure as follows:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<A, TargetSomething>>
```

Although, really, instead of an IGrouping I'd prefer to have a Dictionary or something, basically the equivalent of a Map in other languages.

So far, to group by keys, I used the following code:

```
from smth in smths group smth by smth.A into grp select grp;
```

Which seems pretty verbose for a simple groupBy operation, but what can I do.

Now my question is: How can I add the mapping of Something to TargetSomething using `MyHelper.map(mySomething)` in this LINQ query?

Also, as far as I'm aware, the IEnumerable resulting from this query is lazy so that not the entire content has to be in memory all the time - Is that a misconception? If not, will I lose this feature by adding a map somewhere?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToLookup` to return a `Lookup` which is a kind of multi-valued `Dictionary`.
A `Lookup<TKey, TElement>` implements `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey,TElement>>` so this should work fine for your use case.

```cs
var lookup = smths.ToLookup(smth => smth.A, HelperFunction);
```

The `HelperFunction` should have the return type `TargetSomething` and a single parameter of `Something`.

You could also use a lambda for that:

```cs
var lookup = smths.ToLookup(smth => smth.A, smth => new TargetSomething(...));
```